# The address of a pointer returned by some function gets changed, why?

Tags: c

Sorry I cannot post any reproducible code as it's part of the code of a large project.

The snippet is

```
struct res_data *getRes(int id) {
  struct res_data *ret = malloc(sizeof(*ret));
  /*
  * res.aa = getAA(), etc...
  */

  // print ret got: 0x55ffb23ce000
  fprintf(stderr, "return: ret: %p\n", ret);
  return ret;
}
```

Then

```
struct res_data *data = getRes(id);
fprintf(stderr, "got: %p\n", data);
// print data got: 0xffffffffb23ce000
```

Why is that? Any possible cause?

Comment: Without knowing more, it's possible that there's memory corruption elsewhere.

Comment: I agree with @ChrisLoonam. There's very little to go on from here. All we can see is you're mallocing and then you're trying to print which doesn't give us a lot of information.

Comment: Technically, a cast is required: `fprintf(stderr, "%p\n", (void *)ret);` But I'd be surprised if that's actually the problem.

Comment: Maybe you can create a minimal reproducer, that is the minimal amount of code to get the same behavior

Comment: Please read the [**About**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) page soon and also visit the links describing [**How to Ask a Question**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Providing the necessary details, including your code, compiler warnings and associated errors, if any, will allow everyone here to help you with your question. The problem you describe does not originate in the code snippets posted.

Comment: I'd lay odds you've not properly declared `getRes()` in a header that is used both where it is defined and where it is used, so the place where it is used thinks that it got a 32-bit `int` from `getRes()`, which it then sign-extended to create the pointer saved in `data`. The last 8 hex digits (B23CE000) are the same in both values, but the original pointer in `getRes()` had some zero-bits in the leading 4 bytes, but that in the calling code has all bits `1`, indicating sign-extension. Moral: make sure you have accurate prototypes in force. Make your compiler insist on them. Heed its warnings!

Comment: Making a [mre] includes the concept of cutting everything away which is not related to the actual problem. If you really believed that the shown code is enough to trace the problem, then this idea is not alien to you. Just make sure that the warnings  shown when compiling your code are the same as for the actual code and that the behaviour is the same. You will probably be surprised by suddenly finding the solution yourself.

Comment: If Jonathan's assumption is correct, what compiler do you use or how do you configure your compiler to get no warning for that sort of thing?

Answer (score 5):

<sup>*Transferring comments in answer.*</sup>

### Diagnosis

I'd lay odds you've not properly declared `getRes()` in a header that is used both where it is defined and where it is used, so the place where it is used thinks that it got a 32-bit `int` from `getRes()`, which it then sign-extended to create the pointer saved in `data`.

The last 8 hex digits (B23CE000) are the same in both values, but the original pointer in `getRes()` had some zero-bits in the leading 4 bytes, but that in the calling code has all bits 1, indicating sign-extension.

Moral: make sure you have accurate prototypes in force. Make your compiler insist on them. Heed its warnings!

Here is some code that reproduces the problem — but it is hair-raising to me.  I don't normally publish code like this.

#### `main31.c`

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// Incorrect declaration, but what the compiler infers, more or less
// extern int getRes(int id);

int main(void)
{
    struct res_data *data = (struct res_data *)getRes(31);
    fprintf(stderr, "%6s: 0x%.16" PRIXPTR "\n", __func__, (uintptr_t)data);
    //free(data);    // free fails because the pointer is incorrect
    return 0;
}
```

#### `getres31.c`

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct res_data
{
    int    id;
    char   part2[32];
    double part3;
};

extern struct res_data *getRes(int id);

struct res_data *getRes(int id)
{
    struct res_data *ret = malloc(sizeof(*ret));
    ret->id = id;
    ret->part2[0] = '\0';
    ret->part3 = 0.0;
    fprintf(stderr, "%6s: 0x%.16" PRIXPTR "\n", __func__, (uintptr_t)ret);
    return ret;
}
```

This code is essentially clean, except that the declaration of `getRes()` should be in a header included in both `getres31.c` and `main31.c`.

#### Compilation and running

Normally, I compile with `-Werror` set so the warnings would cause the compilation to fail.

```
$ make so-6051-9209-a
gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -c -o main31.o main31.c
main31.c: In function ‘main’:
main31.c:10:48: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘getRes’; did you mean ‘gets’? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   10 |     struct res_data *data = (struct res_data *)getRes(31);
      |                                                ^~~~~~
      |                                                gets
main31.c:10:29: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
   10 |     struct res_data *data = (struct res_data *)getRes(31);
      |                             ^
gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -c -o getres31.o getres31.c
gcc -o so-6051-9219-a -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes main31.o getres31.o
$
```

When run, the output varies:

```
$ ./so-6051-9219-a
getRes: 0x00007FDF41D02620
  main: 0x0000000041D02620
$ ./so-6051-9219-a
getRes: 0x00007F868AC02AA0
  main: 0xFFFFFFFF8AC02AA0
$
```

Sometimes, the value received in `main()` is interpreted as positive, sometimes as negative, but the value is sign-extended.

### Prescription

The fix is to put the declaration of `getRes()` into a header, and include that header in both source files.

#### `main37.c`

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "getres37.h"

int main(void)
{
    struct res_data *data = getRes(31);
    fprintf(stderr, "%6s: 0x%.16" PRIXPTR "\n", __func__, (uintptr_t)data);
    free(data);
    return 0;
}
```

Note that it is safe to free the data this time.

#### `getres37.c`

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "getres37.h"

struct res_data
{
    int    id;
    char   part2[32];
    double part3;
};

struct res_data *getRes(int id)
{
    struct res_data *ret = malloc(sizeof(*ret));
    ret->id = id;
    ret->part2[0] = '\0';
    ret->part3 = 0.0;
    fprintf(stderr, "%6s: 0x%.16" PRIXPTR "\n", __func__, (uintptr_t)ret);
    return ret;
}
```

#### `getres37.h`

```
#ifndef GETRES37_H_INCLUDED
#define GETRES37_H_INCLUDED

extern struct res_data *getRes(int id);

#endif /* GETRES37_H_INCLUDED */
```

#### Compilation and running

```
$ make so-6051-9219-b
gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -c -o main37.o main37.c
gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -c -o getres37.o getres37.c
gcc -o so-6051-9219-b -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes main37.o getres37.o
$
```

No warnings!

```
$ ./so-6051-9219-b
getRes: 0x00007FBA11600700
  main: 0x00007FBA11600700
$ ./so-6051-9219-b
getRes: 0x00007FED23C02AA0
  main: 0x00007FED23C02AA0
$
```

This time, there's no problem; the value of the pointer in `main()` matches the value in `getRes()`.

Note that the header declares an opaque (incomplete) type `struct res_data` and declares a function that returns a pointer to that type.  The `main()` function cannot dereference the pointer it is returned — it doesn't know (or need to know) the details of the structure.  That's hidden in the file containing `getRes()`.  This is the way that C supports information hiding.  Using an opaque structure type is much safer than the alternative sometimes seen, which is using `void *` everywhere.  That is dangerous as it provides no type safety, unlike the opaque structure types.

Also note that it was easy to create an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))
(or MRE or whatever name SO now uses)
or an
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)).  It really didn't require very much code at all.  But it does make life so much easier — we don't have to do the guesswork!

JFTR: Testing on a MacBook Pro running macOS Mojave 10.14.6, using GCC 9.2.0 plus Xcode 11.3.1.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely cause for this surprising behavior is a missing prototype for `getRes()` when you call this function from `main()`.

Declare the function in a header that you include in both files as

```
extern struct res_data *getRes(int id);
```